# "permisson denied" when I install JDK on Ubuntu

Tags: java, versions

When I install jdk1.7.0-76 on Ubuntu, and input `java -version` on terminal,
it turn out to be "permission denied"

How can I handle this problem?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: what I do are as follows:replace jdk to /usr/lib/jvm/;input "sudo gedit /etc/profile" and some code to configure system variables.then ,input"update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/bin/jvm/jdk1.7.0_76/bin/java/ 300"and another sentence which add"c"after "java".input "uodate-alternatives --config java" and then input"java version".But it remind me that "/usr/bin/java permission denied"

Comment: Sounds like Java is not executable, which suggests an installation problem. Please edit your answer to include the exact steps you took to install it -  `some code to configure system variables` is a bit vague.

Comment: Thank you,and I add "# set java environmentexport JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_76  export JRE_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}/jre  export CLASSPATH=.:${JAVA_HOME}/lib:${JRE_HOME}/lib  export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH  "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/java`

Answer (score 1):

You need to run all commands as root. type sudo -s  then enter your password when asked